# How to set net.core.* and net.ipv4.* sysctl properties in a Docker container

Tags: docker

I am trying to set the following properties in a privileged container as follows:

**Properties**

```
/proc/sys/net/core/rmem_default
/proc/sys/net/core/rmem_max
/proc/sys/net/core/netdev_max_backlog

/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_max_syn_backlog
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_fin_timeout
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_tw_recycle
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_tw_reuse
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_window_scaling
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_max_tw_buckets
```

I am trying to set the properties as follows:

```
[centos@mdc-docker-1 ~]$ docker run -it --rm --privileged --sysctl net.core.rmem_default=20971520 centos:7 bash

docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:402: container init caused \"open /proc/sys/net/core/rmem_default: no such file or directory\"": unknown.
```

According to the [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#configure-namespaced-kernel-parameters-sysctls-at-runtime), net.* is namespaced but I am not sure why I am getting no such file error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the latest version of Docker.

This stuff is only available in Docker > 18.09 version.